# How can I make a button to retrieve the latest information set?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I make a button to retrieve the latest information set
For example, when I write Number: 1
After this write: 2

And: 3

And: 4

I want a button retrieves the last number I write before Number: 4

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXxRi.gif)

Here is my code

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var actionString : String?
@IBOutlet weak var textfiled: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var lblzerous: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func me() {
    lbl.text! =  lbl.text! + "\n" + textfiled.text! + "\n" + "----"
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    self.lblzerous.text =  String(CInt(self.textfiled.text!)! + CInt(self.lblzerous.text!)!)

}
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {


    if textfiled.text! == "" {


        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: " write the number ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
            self.actionString = "Cancel"


        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
    me()

    if Int(lblzerous.text!) >= Int("152") {


        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Gmae Over", message: "  ... \(lblzerous.text!)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "...", style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
            self.actionString = "Cancel"

        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else  {
        print("keep going ....!")
    }
}

@IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Do SomeCode

}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an array variable to serve you as a stack from which you revert the changes:

```
var previousValues: [String] = [String]();
var actionString : String?
@IBOutlet weak var textfiled: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var lblzerous: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
```

Then in **me()** do:

```
func me() {
    lbl.text! =  lbl.text! + "\n" + textfiled.text! + "\n" + "----"
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    self.lblzerous.text =  String(CInt(self.textfiled.text!)! + CInt(self.lblzerous.text!)!)
    previousValues.append(textField.text ?? "error");

}
```

**Edit:** Finally in your retreat button do:

```
@IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
        if previousValues.count > 0 {
            let previousValue = previousValues.removeLast();
            lbl.text! = lbl.text! + "\n-" + previousValue + "\n" + "----";
            let subtracted = (Int(lblzerous.text!)!) - (Int(previousValue)!);
            lblzerous.text = "\(subtracted)"
        }
    }
```

**Edit2:**  Give default values to your labels:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lblzerous.text = "0";
        lbl.text = "0";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but what can i write under [let previousValue = previousValues.removeLast();] i want to remove last  write

Comment: Do you want to change the label of lbl ? For example Remove the last value ?

Comment: @X.BOZO I've amended my answer.

Comment: thank you , but i got error with this code [        let subtracted = (Int(lblzerous.text!)!) - (Int(previousValue)!);
]

Comment: In your  viewDidLoad Method add the following code :  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  lblzerous.text = "0";
  lbl.text = "0";
 }

Comment: yeah thank you it's work , but i still have some problem with lbl.text , the problem is remove all value i want to remove the last value

Comment: @X.BOZO Could you upload your sample project somewhere so I can run it and see what's wrong?

Comment: @X.BOZO Yes, I do. Thing is I would need to work with the code to solve the issue. Why is all the values removed? Can you step through the debugger?

Comment: you can download my project

Comment: @X.BOZO Change the button 1 to : func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
        if previousValues.count > 0 {
            let previousValue = previousValues.removeLast();
            lbl.text! = lbl.text! + "\n-" + previousValue + "\n" + "----";
            let subtracted = (Int(lblzerous.text!)!) - (Int(previousValue)!);
            lblzerous.text = "\(subtracted)"
        }
    }

Comment: see the image please http://g.recordit.co/75SKt3ig4B.gif , can i remove last value without put -1 or -2

Comment: @X.BOZO can't access the image.

Comment: @X.BOZO It won't open, I am sorry.

Comment: did you still here ?